# How to achieve same table width with different column numbers

Tags: longtable, columns, width

I have to print several tables with distinct number of columns. I'm using lingtable because sometimes these tables contains over 300 rows each. Here's the problem.

Even defining a fixed width in cm, when having different column counts, the total width of the table is different.

Why? (I think I'm obviously not aware of some padding or margin)

How do I control the "real" width of the columns?

Here's the code I'm using right now

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{array}
\begin{document}
    \begin{longtable}{|p{2cm}|p{2cm}|p{2cm}|p{2cm}|}
            \hline
            test & test & test & test \\ \hline
            test & test & test & test \\ \hline
            test & test & test & test \\ \hline
            test & test & test & test \\ \hline
            test & test & test & test \\ \hline \hline
    \end{longtable}

    \begin{longtable}{|p{3cm}|p{3cm}|p{1cm}|p{1cm}|}
            \hline
            test & test & test & test asd ads asd asd  \\ \hline
            test & test & test & test asd ads asd asd  \\ \hline
            test & test & test & test asd ads asd asd  \\ \hline
            test & test & test & test asd ads asd asd  \\ \hline
            test & test & test & test asd ads asd asd  \\ \hline \hline
    \end{longtable}

    \begin{longtable}{|p{3cm}|p{3cm}|p{2cm}|}
            \hline
            test & test & test \\ \hline
            test & test & test \\ \hline
            test & test & test \\ \hline
            test & test & test \\ \hline
            test & test & test \\ \hline \hline
    \end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

this is the result (but the sum of column width is the same!):

[image: result]

Comment: `|p{2cm}|p{2cm}|p{2cm}|p{2cm}|}` is 4*2cm + 8*\tabcolsep + 5*\arrayrulewidth wide

Comment: OK, now I understand better. is `\tabcolstep` placed in each side of each column?

Comment: OK, now i finally understand, post that as an answer and I'll accept, finally found the array and source2e documentation pages.

Comment: If you have a modern distribution you shouldn't have to `find` the documentation just type `texdoc array` or `texdoc longtable` etc and the pdf should open

Comment: I'm relatively new in LaTeX, i didn't knew about source2e until i faced this problem. Thanks!!

Comment: I answered the `p` column case but I just noticed that you indicated that you'd  also be interest in natural width `lcr` columns. In that case it is easiest to make sure that the columns are the same width in the tables by putting the widest entry in _every_ table and use a longtable `\kill` row so the wide entry is only used to calculate the column widths and doesn't appear in the table

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{array}
\newlength\mylength
\begin{document}

\setlength{\mylength}{\dimexpr 8cm -8\tabcolsep- 5\arrayrulewidth}

    \begin{longtable}{|*4{p{\dimexpr\mylength / 4\relax}|}}
            \hline
            test & test & test & test \\ \hline
            test & test & test & test \\ \hline
            test & test & test & test \\ \hline
            test & test & test & test \\ \hline
            test & test & test & test \\ \hline \hline
    \end{longtable}

    \begin{longtable}{|*2{p{\dimexpr 3\mylength/8}|}
                       *2{p{\dimexpr   \mylength/8}|}}
            \hline
            test & test & test & test asd ads asd asd  \\ \hline
            test & test & test & test asd ads asd asd  \\ \hline
            test & test & test & test asd ads asd asd  \\ \hline
            test & test & test & test asd ads asd asd  \\ \hline
            test & test & test & test asd ads asd asd  \\ \hline \hline
    \end{longtable}

\setlength{\mylength}{\dimexpr 8cm -6\tabcolsep- 4\arrayrulewidth}
    \begin{longtable}{|*2{p{\dimexpr 3\mylength/8}|}
                          p{\dimexpr 2\mylength/8}|}
            \hline
            test & test & test \\ \hline
            test & test & test \\ \hline
            test & test & test \\ \hline
            test & test & test \\ \hline
            test & test & test \\ \hline \hline
    \end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use one of the extension packages which allows you to combine the facilities of `tabularx` with those of `longtable`. `tabularx` lets you specify the width of the tabular. On its own, it is incompatible with `longtable` but several packages are available which allow you to use its syntax with long tables. For example:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{ltablex}
  \keepXColumns
\usepackage{array}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tabularx}{110mm}{|*{4}{X|}}
            \hline
            test & test & test & test \\ \hline
            test & test & test & test \\ \hline
            test & test & test & test \\ \hline
            test & test & test & test \\ \hline
            test & test & test & test \\ \hline \hline
    \end{tabularx}

    \begin{tabularx}{110mm}{|*{2}{>{\hsize=1.5\hsize}X|}*{2}{>{\hsize=.5\hsize}X|}}
            \hline
            test & test & test & test asd ads asd asd  \\ \hline
            test & test & test & test asd ads asd asd  \\ \hline
            test & test & test & test asd ads asd asd  \\ \hline
            test & test & test & test asd ads asd asd  \\ \hline
            test & test & test & test asd ads asd asd  \\ \hline \hline
    \end{tabularx}

    \begin{tabularx}{110mm}{|*{2}{>{\hsize=1.125\hsize}X|}>{\hsize=.75\hsize}X|}
            \hline
            test & test & test \\ \hline
            test & test & test \\ \hline
            test & test & test \\ \hline
            test & test & test \\ \hline
            test & test & test \\ \hline \hline
    \end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

[image: ltablex tabulars of fixed width]